# 802.15.4 devices information

Tags: zigbee

i am making 802.15.4 protocol.

I'm confused about device's information such as short address.

When multiple device try to associate coordinator, coordinator have to allocate

short address to each device.

Therefore, Coordinator should have device's information which are associated.

After then, allocated short address is not duplicated.

I read document, but there was no info what i mentioned.

How coordinator keep associated device's info ?

Can i make it own my way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the address allocation (and duplicate address resolution) is defined above the MAC layer, which in ZigBee is the ZigBee Pro specification (http://www.zigbee.org/zigbee-for-developers/network-specifications/zigbeepro/). The 802.15.4 specification defines the MAC layer.

"Therefore, Coordinator should have device's information which are associated.
After then, allocated short address is not duplicated."

This is not correct. The parent (an FFD - i.e. Coord or Router) will allocate the address, which is not always the coordinator. An address conflict resolution mechanism is implemented in the ZigBee protocol stack in case 2 FFD's in the network allocate the same address.

"Can i make it own my way ?"

If you are developing your own protocol on top of 802.15.4, and not using ZigBee (as the tag suggests).

Regards, TC.

Comment: So, address allocation and duplicate address resolution is not define defined in 802.15.4 ? If i want to solve that issue, i have to use Zigbee or develop my own protocol on top of 802.15.4 ?